# Attempting to parse XML/JSON from an API output

Tags: php, json, xml

OK... I am using PHP 5 (be gentle, still learning PHP). CURL is enabled. Attempting to load XML or JSON output from an API to an object and nothing happens. When I manually execute the URL in question, I get what I am expecting.

Here is my code:

```
class XmlToJson {
    public function Parse ($url) {
        $fileContents = file_get_contents($url);
        $fileContents = str_replace(array("\n", "\r", "\t"), '', $fileContents);
        $fileContents = trim(str_replace('"', "'", $fileContents));
        $simpleXml = simplexml_load_string($fileContents);
        $json = json_encode($simpleXml);
        return $json;
    }
}

$_MySQLServer = "localhost";
$_MySQLServerUserName = "";
$_MySQLServerPassword = "";
$_MySQLDatabaseName = "";

$_SSActiveWear_UserID = "*****";
$_SSActiveWear_APIKey = "*****";
$_SSActiveWear_APIBaseURL = "https://*****/v2";
$_CategoryURL = "/categories/";
$_StylesURL = "/styles/";
$_ProductsURL = "/products/";
$_SpecsURL = "/specs/";
$_SSActiveWear_MediaType = "xml";

//$_conn = mysqli_connect($_MySQLServer, $_MySQLServerUserName, $_MySQLServerPassword, $_MySQLDatabaseName);

//Insert or Update Categories
$_URL = $_SSActiveWear_APIBaseURL . $_CategoryURL;
$_URL = $_URL . "?mediatype=$_SSActiveWear_MediaType&UserName=$_SSActiveWear_UserID&Password=$_SSActiveWear_APIKey";

$OBJ = simplexml_load_string($_URL);

print_r($OBJ);
```

What am I doing wrong?

**Edit 1**

Added the following code:

```
$xml = simplexml_load_file($_URL) or die("Error: Cannot create object");
print_r($xml);
```

and it dies. Does that mean that there is something wrong with the code?

Comment: Can you run fiddler on the machine while this run to verify your call is going out and returning data to your php?  If that is happening, then your code is wrong.  If there are errors on the call, then you can see them in the fiddler response screen at the bottom.  See http://www.telerik.com/fiddler

Comment: No errors. In fact the result was an http-200 on a post so I have no idea why its not working :(.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I FINALLY figured it out... More to the point I finally found a site on Google that helped. It is the first answer in [fsockopen with http authentication problem](http://forums.devnetwork.net/viewtopic.php?f=1&t=43912).

So here is the code that works:

```
file_get_contents("https://$_SSActiveWear_UserID:$_SSActiveWear_APIKey@$_SSActiveWear_APIBaseURL$_CategoryURL/?mediatype=$_SSActiveWear_MediaType");
```

mediatype can be either json or xml

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
$OBJ = simplexml_load_string(file_get_contents($_URL));
```

If you want to know why your code is not working, you are trying to load XML from URL but "simplexml_load_string" loads XML from string.

Comment: No dice. still empty.

Comment: Are you sure about API returns XML output ?

Comment: Absoultly, I tried the URL by hand myself. It also returns JSON.

Comment: If not,you can try 

$OBJ = json_decode( file_get_contents( $_URL ) );

Comment: Tried that as well, no dice - still :(